# NSManagedObject Transformable Array of custom objects null/unpopulated

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a core data model like so:

```
User
- objectId
- access (transformable - array of "User_Access")

CustomObject
- objectId
- name
- etc

User_Access
- customObject
```

The objects save correctly and the transformable access array properly is filled, but on the second use of the app, the "access" array is an array of unfilled objects:

```
"<User_Access: 0x6060001746e0> (entity: <null>; id: (null); data: <fault>)"
```

I'm using a fetch request like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
[fetch setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[fetch setIncludesSubentities:YES];
[fetch setIncludesSubentities:YES];
NSArray *test = [[SPModel objectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
    
if (test.count == 0) {
    return nil;
}
    
User *user = (User *)test.firstObject;
```

The fetch request fetches the properties of the user object perfectly, but the transformable "access" array is unpopulated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Instead of using transformables to store an array of core data objects, use a relationship and set the destination to the custom object class, and change the type from `To One` to `To Many`.

This will require you change your property in your header file to an `NSSet` instead of an `NSArray`.